# How can i host MERN website on plesk (windows)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, hosting, mern, plesk

I have plesk(windows) hosting. I want to host MERN app on it. I am able to add `nodejs` app on it but cant add `react` app. i have database on `mongodb atlas`.
I cant even set custom variables on it.

on hosting `nodejs` app `"/"` `res.send("running")` works fine but no other route work. and cant even see my react app.

Anyone has any idea how can i host it to Plesk.

Answer (score 0):

If you have VPS hosting you can try the below steps.

Open the file manager and check for the folder create-react-app. Add the following .htaccess to your public folder.

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

Run npm run-script build

FRP the entire contents of the build directory to your Linux server on Plesk

If you have a shared hosting service, you may not host MERN app.

Comment: dont have a vps. its shared hosting i guess

Comment: In this case, you should contact your hosting support or move to a VPS solution.